# Terraform mailformed policy document

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

im trying to create an aws iam role policy resource on terraform but i got the following error message:  ***MalformedPolicyDocument: The policy failed legacy parsing***

Already tried to parse on json formatters and things like that and the json policy looks fine so idk what im missing, thanks for the help!

```
policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
        "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
        "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
        "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
        "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
        "ec2:DescribeVpcs"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:${var.REGION}:network-interface/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:Subnet": [
            "${element(aws_subnet.private.*.id, 0)}",
            "${element(aws_subnet.private.*.id, 1)}"
          ],
          "ec2:AuthorizedService": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.codebuild.arn}",
        "${aws_s3_bucket.codebuild.arn}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
```

Comment: Does it fail during plan or during apply? You need tureo make sure that your variable interpolations are working correctly.

Comment: ive already setted values by hand in the code and got the same error message, so i guess the interpolation its working well

Comment: Use a [`data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy" {...}`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) to not have to manually write the json and have a simpler syntax.

Comment: Also - did you try this exact IAM policy manually in AWS Console?

Comment: no i didnt, just did the policy on terraform, im going to try it now

Comment: tried it on aws console and got the error on "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:network-interface/*" line, the error was: Missing ARN Field: Resource ARNs must include at least 6 fields and include the following structure:: arn: partition: service: region: account: resource

Comment: Yes, you are missing the account id in the arn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen the error before, but Googling tells me the JSON parser/processor AWS is using for IAM policies seems very picky. I.e. `Version` has to come before `Statement`, etc.

In your particular case based on a [comment](https://github.com/99designs/iamy/issues/65#issuecomment-684074636) I found I **guess** it might be about white space around your value.
The comment says:

> Additionally, you cannot have an space before the initial "{".

Thus in Terraform what you might need is a `trimspace` around the whole value:

```
policy = trimspace(<<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
[... redacted for readability]
}
POLICY
)
```

Comment: Even with trimspace function i got the same error, thats kind strange because below this resource i did another quite similar, look: ***  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
POLICY***

Comment: i guess i was wrong and it really could be the variables interpolations, but when i do terraform plan the output on console looks good, like any variable undefined or something like that...